# Better approach for evaluating expressions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that accepts 2 parameters -

1. expression (string eg. `'x+y'`)
2. variables (object eg. `{ 'x': [7, 1], 'y': [2, 9] }`)

My goal is to return the maximum value possible from the function by substituting the variables with their corresponding values.

For eg., the maximum value possible from the above expression is 16 when x = 7 and y = 9.

My Code -

```
const findMax = (exp, variables) => {
    let result = [];
    for (let key in variables) {
        result.push(variables[key].map((elem) => {
            return key + ':' + elem;
        }));
    }

    result = result[0].flatMap(d => result[1].map(v => d + ',' + v));
    let max = 0;

    for (let variables of result) {
        let expression = exp;
        let temp = variables.split(',');

        let arr1 = temp[0].split(':');
        let arr2 = temp[1].split(':');
        console.log("arr1 values = ", arr1[0], arr1[1]);
        console.log("arr2 values = ", arr2[0], arr2[1]);

        expression = expression.replace(arr1[0], arr1[1]).replace(arr2[0], arr2[1]);

        let res = eval(expression);
        if (res > max) {
            max = res;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

The above function works, but I have few issues that I wish to resolve -

1. The above function is too complicated. Looking for an efficient/better way to process it.
2. It can only process for 2 variables. I want to process 1 or more variables. For eg., the expression can be - `x + 2y - 3z` and variables - `{ 'x': [7, 8], 'y': [2, 7], 'z': [4, 5] }`
3. Want to avoid using `eval()`

Possible inputs -

1. exp - `2*x+3`, variables - `{'x': [1, 2]}`
2. exp - `2*3-1`, variables - `{}`
3. exp - `8/y-z+k`, variables - `{'y': [1, 2], 'z': [5, 2], 'k': [2, 6]}`

Comment: do you have other examples of the expression? which operators do you use?

Comment: Expressions can include - `+, -, *, /` i.e addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

Comment: I have added additional inputs for clarity.

Comment: Instead of having to parse `'x+y'` you could pass a function `(x,y)=>x+y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `eval` you'll have to write your own parser, which is a gruesome and error-prone task.
Many such parsers exist, but you'll have to adapt them to your "multiple-valued variables" idea.

Also, a brute-force search for the maximal result will have an exponential computation time, so don't expect it to work on hundreds or thousands of variables.

### Parsing by hand

Here is an example of bare bone expression evaluator using a generator to enumerate all possible values of your variables.

```js
function evaluate (expression, variables) {
    
    // minimal sanity check
    if ((expression.match(/[(]/g) ?? []).length !== (expression.match(/[)]/g) ?? []).length)
        throw "Unbalanced parenthesis";

    // simplistic parser (minimal handling of unary minus)
    const tokens = ('('+expression+')')                 // extra enclosing parenthesis
                .replace(/\s/g,'')                      // remove blanks
                .replace(/\(-/g,'(:')                   // mark unary minus as :
                .replace(/(\w+|\d+|[+\-/*:()])/g,"$1#") // tag tokens with #
                .slice(0,-1)                            // remove trailing #
                .split("#");                            // split into tokens
                
    // shunting-yard to produce a postfix expression
    let postfix = [], s_op = [];
    const prio = { '(':0, '+':1, '-':1, '*':2, '/':2, ':':3 }; // operator priorities
    for (let tok of tokens) {
        if      (!isNaN(+tok))     postfix.push(+tok); // constant
        else if (tok.match(/\w+/)) postfix.push( tok); // variable
        else if (tok === '(') s_op.push(tok);
        else if (tok === ')') {
            // will fail if parenthesis are unbalanced
            let op; while ((op = s_op.pop()) !== '(') postfix.push(op);
        }
        else {
            while ((s_op.length > 0) && (prio[s_op[s_op.length-1]] >= prio[tok])) {
                postfix.push(s_op.pop());
            }
            s_op.push(tok);
        }
    }
    if (s_op.length != 0) throw "operator stack should be empty";
    
    // postfix evaluator
    const evaluate = function (values) {
        let s_val = []; // operand stack (numerical values)
        for (let tok of postfix) {
            switch (tok) {
                case ':' :                      s_val.push(-s_val.pop()    ); break;
                case '+' : var a = s_val.pop(); s_val.push (s_val.pop() + a); break;
                case '-' : var a = s_val.pop(); s_val.push (s_val.pop() - a); break;
                case '*' : var a = s_val.pop(); s_val.push (s_val.pop() * a); break;
                case '/' : var a = s_val.pop(); s_val.push (s_val.pop() / a); break;
                default  : s_val.push ((typeof (tok) == 'number') ? tok : values[tok]); break;
            }
        }
        return s_val[0];
    }

    // generates all possible tuples of values
    const combinations = function* (variables) {
        let max = 1; for (let values of Object.values(variables)) max *= values.length;
        for (let iter = 0 ; iter != max ; iter++) {
            let values = {}, i = iter;
            for (let name of Object.keys(variables)) {
                let len = variables[name].length
                values[name] = variables[name][i % len];
                i = Math.floor(i/len);
            }
            yield values;
        }
    }
    
    // maximize the expression over all possible combinations of values
    let val_max = -Number.MAX_VALUE, vars_max;
    for (let vars of combinations(variables)) {
        let val = evaluate (vars);
console.log (JSON.stringify(vars),val);
        if (val > val_max) {
            vars_max = vars;
            val_max = val;
        }
    }
console.log (">>>",JSON.stringify(vars_max),val_max);
    return { vars:vars_max, val:val_max };
}

evaluate("2*x+3", { x:[1,2] });
evaluate("2*3-1", {});
evaluate("8/y-z+k", { y:[1, 2], z:[5, 2], k:[2, 6] });
evaluate("(x-5)*(y+5)/((z-3)*(t+5))", { x:[-5,3], y:[-1,3], z:[5, 3, 2], t:[-5, 6] });
```

Beware: a divide by zero can generate +Infinity, which might lead to the selection of an unexpected set of values.
The parser only barely supports the unary minus, i.e. `-5` or `-(-5)` will work, but not `--5` or other fancy stuff a proper grammar would allow.
Unary `+` is not supported at all.
Error checking is minimal and nothing is optimized.
An ill-formed expression is very likely to cause a disaster (infinite loop, out of memory, you name it).

### Using the Boooh! function

The Function That Shall Not Be Used Ever allows to write far less code, but God might kill some kittens for this blasphemy...

```js
function evaluate (expression, variables) {
    
    // generates all possible tuples of values
    const combinations = function* (variables) {
        let max = 1; for (let values of Object.values(variables)) max *= values.length;
        for (let iter = 0 ; iter != max ; iter++) {
            let setter = "", i = iter;
            for (let name of Object.keys(variables)) {
                let len = variables[name].length
                setter += name + "=" + variables[name][i % len] + ",";
                i = Math.floor(i/len);
            }
            yield setter;
        }
    }
    
    // maximize the expression over all possible combinations of values
    let val_max = -Number.MAX_VALUE, vars_max;
    for (let setter of combinations(variables)) {
        let val = eval (setter+expression);
console.log (setter," -> ",val);
        if (val > val_max) {
            vars_max = setter;
            val_max = val;
        }
    }
console.log (">>>",vars_max,val_max);
    return { vars:vars_max, val:val_max };
}

evaluate("2*x+3", { x:[1,2] });
evaluate("2*3-1", {});
evaluate("8/y-z+k", { y:[1, 2], z:[5, 2], k:[2, 6] });
evaluate("(x-5)*(y+5)/((z-3)*(t+5))", { x:[-5,3], y:[-1,3], z:[5, 3, 2], t:[-5, 6] });
```

The result is a bit awkward, it's just the variable initializations list, but you can easily reformat it to your liking.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I believe I will use `eval()` instead of a custom parser.

Comment: My pleasure. A wise decision, in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

There it is:

```js
let findMax = (exp, variables) => {
  let clearRepeatedArrayItems = (array) => {
    const obj = {};
    array.forEach(item => obj[item] = item);
    return Object.keys(obj);
  };
  
  let allCombinations = (variables, str) => {
    let combinations = [];
    const keys = Object.keys(variables);
    keys.forEach(key => {
        const variable = variables[key];
        
        const allExceptCurrentKeys = keys.filter(k => k !== key);
        const allExceptCurrentObj = {};
        allExceptCurrentKeys.forEach(k => {
          allExceptCurrentObj[k] = variables[k];
        });
                 
        
        variable.forEach(value => {
          const item = `${key}:${value}`;
          
          if (allExceptCurrentKeys.length) {
            combinations = combinations.concat(allCombinations(allExceptCurrentObj, str ? `${str},${item}` : item));
          } else {
            combinations.push(`${str},${item}`);
          }
              
        });
    });

    return combinations;
  };

  const combinations = allCombinations(variables);
  
  const combWithSortedKey = combinations.map(comb => comb.split(',').sort((a, b) => a.split(':')[0].localeCompare(b.split(':')[0])).join(','));
  const uniqueCombinations = clearRepeatedArrayItems(combWithSortedKey);

  let max = 0;
  let combinationUsed = '';

  uniqueCombinations.forEach(comb => {
    let expression = exp;
    comb.split(',').forEach(pair => {
      const tokens = pair.split(':');
      expression = expression.replace(new RegExp(tokens[0], 'g'), tokens[1]);
    });

    const value = eval(expression);

    if (value > max) {
      max = value;
      combinationUsed = `{ ${comb.replace(/,/g, ', ').replace(/:/g, ': ')} }`;
    }
  });
 
  return { max, combinationUsed };
};
```